# atom cant read csv with pandas same directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv, atom-editor

The CSV File and the .py file are in the same directory underneath some other directory.

```
upper_directory
 - lower_directory
    - test.py (where I read the csv file from)
    - student_data.csv
```

What I try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('student_data.csv')
```

What I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/Desktop/flask_dash_directory/myproject/dashboard/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("student_data.csv")
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/iwasiwas/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'student_data.csv' does not exist: b'student_data.csv'
```

How can I fix this without typing out the full path? (it works with the full - but I need to get it to work without my local full path for deployment and I don't understand why it doesn't work since both the .py file and the .csv file are in the same directoy.)

Thank you!

Comment: can you try with `ìmport os`,  
`df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'student_data.csv'))`

Comment: hey. thank you for the reponse. my mistake was that I wasn't in the correct directory when running the file in the terminal